# Cohen's d for a glm model with interaction

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to find the Cohen's d effect sizes for the main effects of my model.

Here's a bit of code to create part of the data frame:

```
RA <- c(40, 32, 41, 9, 27, 31, 29, 28, 48, 5, 18, 5, 3, 31, 31)
Sex <- c('M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F')
Mass <- c(10.9535, 4.3235, 9.2485, 4.8235, 6.896, 8.2075, 9.281, 0.734, 9.603, 0.973, 10.3435, 0.9505, 7.384, 6.935, 8.936)
Exp <- c('Single', 'Mixed', 'Single','Double','Single','Single','Single','Double','Single','Mixed','Double','Mixed','Mixed','Single','Single')
LastExp <- c('W','L','L','L','W','L','W','L','W','W','W','L','L','L','L')
```

Then my glm model is:

```
RAmodel <- glm(RA~Sex*Exp*LastExp+Mass,family=poisson())
```

I was able to find the Cohen's d effect sizes for each pairwise comparison using the emmeans package as follows:

```
emRA <- emmeans(RAmodel, ~Sex*Exp*LastExp)
eff_size(emRA, sigma = sigma(RAmodel),edf=31)
```

However, what I really want is to find the Cohen's d effect sizes of the main model so I might be able to make claims like "Exp has a bigger effect on RA than LastExp" or something like that. What I have in mind is to somehow get an output that looks a little like what I'm getting from:

```
car::Anova(RAmodel)
```

but include the Cohen's d in it. I tried to use the effsize package but I think the interaction in the model and non-numeric variables is making it difficult.

I apologize in advance if some of these lines don't work without the full dataset. I would appreciate any assistance in this.

Comment: If Exp (say) is involved in any of the interactions, it may not make sense to claim that "Exp has a bigger effect than LastExp", because the effect of Exp changes depening on the presence (or absence) of other factors.

Comment: @Limey so perhaps I do want the pairwise effect sizes... I can say something like "for males, Double L had a greater effect on RA than Mixed L" as long as it has the interaction in the interpretation? 
So I guess I can't really do broad, general statements here (like the example above) anyways because of that interaction?

Comment: I don't think Cohen's d even makes sense for this model, because there is no homogeneous error SD to use as a reference. DWhat you get from `sigma()` is not suitable for that purpose, as it measures how well the model fits , not any kind of SD of the responses.